# Remove action plugin

Tags: plugins, actions

i have installed the theme-my-login plugin and i want change the password_fields function:
this is the code of custom-password.php of the plugin:

```
     /**
 * Loads the module
 *
 * @since 6.0
 * @access protected
 */
protected function load() {
    add_action( 'register_form',       array( &$this, 'password_fields' ) );
    add_filter( 'registration_errors', array( &$this, 'password_errors' ) );
    add_filter( 'random_password',     array( &$this, 'set_password'    ) );

    add_action( 'signup_extra_fields',       array( &$this, 'ms_password_fields'       ) );
    add_action( 'signup_hidden_fields',      array( &$this, 'ms_hidden_password_field' ) );
    add_filter( 'wpmu_validate_user_signup', array( &$this, 'ms_password_errors'       ) );
    add_filter( 'add_signup_meta',           array( &$this, 'ms_save_password'         ) );

    add_action( 'tml_new_user_registered', array( &$this, 'remove_default_password_nag' ) );
    add_action( 'approve_user',            array( &$this, 'remove_default_password_nag' ) );

    add_filter( 'tml_register_passmail_template_message', array( &$this, 'register_passmail_template_message' ) );
    add_action( 'tml_request',                            array( &$this, 'action_messages'                    ) );

    add_filter( 'registration_redirect', array( &$this, 'registration_redirect' ) );
}

/**
 * Outputs password fields to registration form
 *
 * Callback for "register_form" hook in file "register-form.php", included by Theme_My_Login_Template::display()
 *
 * @see Theme_My_Login::display()
 * @since 6.0
 * @access public
 */
public function password_fields() {
    $template =& Theme_My_Login::get_object()->get_active_instance();
    ?>
    <p><label for="pass1<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Password' ); ?></label>
    <input autocomplete="off" name="pass1" id="pass1<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" size="20" value="" type="password" /></p>
    <p><label for="pass2<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Confirm Password', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></label>
    <input autocomplete="off" name="pass2" id="pass2<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" size="20" value="" type="password" /></p>
    <?php
}
```

in functions.php i have added this but not working:

```
     function init_wp() {

// remove parent theme's header content action
remove_action('register_form', 'password_fields');

// add child theme's header content action
add_action('register_form', 'cust_password_fields');

     }
     add_action('init', 'init_wp');

function cust_password_fields(){

}
```

any ideas ?

Comment: This is a plain PHP problem: Class vs. function. `function_name` vs. `array( $this, 'method_name' )` or in other words: `array( 'Class_Name', 'method_name' );`. Close voting as _off topic_. Please consult php.net and SO for further info about this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you kaiser,
your comment is helpful but insufficient, so the solution is :

to remove function in other class in wordpress :

```
    remove_action('register_form', array(Theme_My_Login_Custom_Passwords::get_object(),'password_fields' ) );
```

Thank you